How to use Flan-T5 with LoRA on multi gpu system?
When using Huggingface with 'google/flan-t5-base' model, I get the error:
RuntimeError: Expected all tensors to be on the same device, but found at least two devices, cuda:0 and cuda:1! (when checking argument for argument index in method wrapper__index_select)

I've found in the transformers.py file in _wrap_model, the model becomes model = nn.DataParallel(model), which seems ok b/c I have 3 gpus on the machine.  However, it seems like the data is not setup to work with this (hence the cuda device error I mentioned above).
Is this a known issue?
I'm using transformers library version 4.44.0.
Here is a snippet of the code:
model_name='google/flan-t5-base'
model = AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM.from_pretrained(model_name, torch_dtype=torch.bfloat16)

dataset = load_dataset(“knkarthick/dialogsum”)
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)

def tokenize_function(example):
    start_prompt = 'Summarize the following conversation.\n\n'
    end_prompt = '\n\nSummary: '
    prompt = [start_prompt + dialogue + end_prompt for dialogue in example["dialogue"]]
    example['input_ids'] = torch.tensor(tokenizer(prompt, padding="max_length", truncation=True, return_tensors="pt").input_ids)
    example['labels'] = torch.tensor(tokenizer(example["summary"], padding="max_length", truncation=True, return_tensors="pt").input_ids)

    return example

tokenized_datasets = dataset.map(tokenize_function, batched=True)
tokenized_datasets = tokenized_datasets.remove_columns(['id', 'topic', 'dialogue', 'summary',])
tokenized_datasets = tokenized_datasets.filter(lambda example, index: index % 100 == 0, with_indices=True)
lora_config = LoraConfig(r=32,lora_alpha=32,target_modules=["q", "v"],lora_dropout=0.05,bias="none",task_type=TaskType.SEQ_2_SEQ_LM # FLAN-T5)

peft_model = get_peft_model(model, lora_config)
peft_training_args = TrainingArguments(output_dir="./output", learning_rate=1e-3, num_train_epochs=1,logging_steps=1,max_steps=1)
peft_trainer = Trainer(model=peft_model,args=peft_training_args,train_dataset=tokenized_datasets["train"],)
peft_trainer.train()


Sadly, I never had the chance to do multi-GPU training. Although, I can say that the DistributedDataParrallel should be used, and not the simpler DataParrallel alone. See torch documentation and tutorial. Notably, this discussion might interest you?
